# Need a java.util.regex to retrieve value in quotes

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have this string:

```
String str = "message version=1 filename=\"double \"\"quote\"\" file.txt\" size=32591";
```

I want to get the filename value with a regex. What I've used so far is:

```
Matcher fileNameMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\s*filename=\"(.*?)\"\\s*").matcher(str);
while (fileNameMatcher.find()) {
    int n = fileNameMatcher.groupCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        this.fileName = fileNameMatcher.group(i + 1);
}
```

If there are quotes in the filename, it will always be doubled (""), so I want a regex that will ignore double doublequotes and retrieve the quoted filename value from the message

Comment: Try `Pattern.compile("filename=\"([^\"]*(?:\"{2}[^\"]*)*)\"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Pattern.compile("filename=\"([^\"]*(?:\"{2}[^\"]*)*)\"")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZlnbS/1).

**Pattern details**

- `filename="` - a literal string
- `([^"]*(?:"{2}[^"]*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^"]*` - 0 or more chars other than `"`
  - `(?:"{2}[^"]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of a double `"` char and then 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.